# Deja dup with LUKS

Tags: backup, encryption, luks, deja-dup

I have my home partition backed up on an external hard drive via Deja Dup. This is my only partition except my boot partition. I’d like to enable LUKS on it, so would it work to just do it (which would effectively format it) and then to restore in Deja Dup? Or does it not work with encrypted partitions?

Comment: Which distro and version of Linux are you using? Are you asking if you can restore a backup made from an unencrypted partition be restored into an encrypted partition? Why not?

Comment: Yes that is what I am asking! I use Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: It should work.